# JQuery dialog box Insert/Update records?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, coldfusion

I'm working on simple table where I have Add button and Edit option for each row in my table. I would like this to work with JQuery dialog box if possible. My code is not working and I need a help. If you can please take a look and let me know what should be modify. Thanks in advance.

Here is my User.cfm code:

```
<!--- ******************** Start  ******************** --->
<head>
    <title>User Table</title>
</head>

<cfparam name="ActiveP" default="1">

<cfquery name="qryUser" datasource="UsersData">
    SELECT UserID, Date, Name, Age,  
           Case when Active = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Active
    FROM Users
    <cfif ActiveP EQ 1>
    WHERE Active > 0
    </cfif>
    ORDER BY Date DESC
</cfquery>

<div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    <span onClick="User()"><strong> Add User</strong></span>
</div>

<table id='gwTable'>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
        <cfoutput query="qryUsers">
            <tr>
                <td>#DateFormat(Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
                <td>#Name#</td>
                <td>#Age#</td>
                <td>#Active#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tbody>    
</table>

<cfoutput>
    <div id="dialog" title="User Record" style="display:none"/>

    </div>
</cfoutput>

    <!--- ******************** End Main Output ******************** --->

    <script>
        //Function to call AddUser in AjaxFunctions
        function AddUser(tblRow){
            var RowId = $(tblRow).attr('id');
            objStuEvents = {}; 
            var whObj = {"url":"/apps/User.cfc?method=getUser&returnformat=json"};
            gwAjaxPost(whObj,{"UserID":RowId},showUsers);

        }
        //Showing all results from AjaxFunction
        function ShowUser(whObj){
            var numRecs = whObj.RECORDCOUNT;
            if( numRecs == "0" )
                $('#gwExisting').html("No records exist");
            else
            {
                objStuEvents = whObj;
                //Create Table
                var tbl = "<tableid='gwTable'><thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Name</th>     <th>Age</th><th>Active</th></tr></thead>";
                tbl += "<tbody>";
                for(var i=1; i<=numRecs; i++)
                {
                    var jsRec = whObj.DATA[i];
                    tbl += "<tr><td>"+jsRec.DATE+"</td>";
                    tbl += "<td>"+jsRec.NAME+"</td>";
                    tbl += "<td>"+jsRec.AGE+"</td>";
                    tbl += "<td>"+jsRec.ACTIVE+"</td></tr>"
                }
                tbl += "</tbody></table>";
                //Call for JQuery dialog box with dialog id
                $('#dialog').html(tbl);
                //Setting of height and width for dialog box 
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                    height: 400,
                    width: 600
                    });

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Here is my User.cfc code:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="AddUser" access="remote" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfargument name="UserID" type="string" required="yes"> 

        <cfset var fncResults = structNew()>
        <cfset var recs = StructNew()>

            <cfquery name="qryUsers" datasource="UserData">
                SELECT UserID, Date, Name, Age, Active
                FROM Users
                WHERE UserID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#UserID#">
                ORDER BY Date DESC
            </cfquery>

            <cfset fncResults.recordcount = qryPlugins.recordcount>
            <cfloop query="qryPlugins">
                <cfset recs[currentRow] = StructNew()>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].UserID = ' ' & qryUsers.UserID>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].Date = ' ' & qryUsers.Date>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].Name = ' ' & qryUsers.Name>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].Age = ' ' & qryUsers.Age>
                <cfset recs[currentRow].Active = ' ' & qryUsers.Active>
            </cfloop>

            <cfset fncResults.status = "200">
            <cfset fncResults.data = recs>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset fncResults.status = "400">
            <cfset fncResults.message = "Invalid access attempt">           
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn fncResults>           

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: this is a bit beyond me so i might be talking nonsense, but it seems to me that when you output the query in the table, theres no link from each row to a UserID that the jquery would pass to the cfc?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Without knowing more 1) Did you first verify the function works correctly when called from a browser? If not, do that first. ie `http://yourserver/path/to/YourComponent.cfc?method=getUser&returnformat=json&UserID={someTestValue}` 2) Please [edit] your post to include any javascript error messages from your browser's debugging tool and/or any CF error messages from the logs.

Comment: Assuming `gwAjaxPost()` is your own function that fires off the AJAX request, and `showUsers` is the callback function....then `showUsers` is not defined.